# Light-activating a motor

Tags: ldr

I have an LDR and it reads higher than 17K ohm when the lighting conditions meet my requirements.
I wish to be able to activate a vibrator motor (coin type 3 Volts) when the LDR has a resistance higher than 17K Ohm.
I have no idea though how to do so.
Any ideas more than welcome!

Comment: This is not really the place to get ideas about how to proceed with a project. It is a place to ask specific questions that have specific answers. You should define the resistance below which the requirements are not met (17K minus X%) in addition the resistance above which the requirements are met (17K).  Then study how resistance is measured with a meter and how that measurement could be used to activate a the vibrator motor. Determine how much current the vibrator motor requires. Write down the facts and figures that you learn. Think about how you might diagram the project.

Comment: This question is really too broad for EE.SE. You should try to learn about existing circuits that use LDRs to control something and then come back when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a microcontroller to control the whole setup.  The LDR could be placed in series with a resistor and then use the ADC of the microcontroller to get the voltage which corresponds to the light intensity.  The use the microcontroller to control the vibration motor.  Most probably you would need a transistor in order to be able to provide the necessary power.

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite components is the cmos schmitt trigger, 74HC14 or 74hc4093.
These are really versatile, make simple circuits, are robust, come 6 to a pack, and are perfect for this.

Because they are schmitt triggers, you get a clean switch as the light increases.

You can make oscillators, delays, single-shot pulses with them. Filthy cheap too.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSClSP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHfCod.png)</sup>